# SwiftUI: Cannot show alert with WKWebView and WebView: UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui, webview, alert, wkwebview, uiviewrepresentable

I need a way to understand why I cannot show alert messages in swiftui for this code, I'd like to show alert if something happens while loading web page (also monitoring cookies, but is another task) I even tried using a UIAlertController, but with no success. , I think my issue is about alert with is presenting one after the other, but I'm presenting only one. :

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showWebView = false
    @State private var showError = false
    @State private var errorMessage = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("open WebView") {
            if !showError {
                showWebView = true
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWebView) {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
                WebView(url: url) { error in
                    self.errorMessage = error
                    self.showError = true
                }
            } else {
                Text("not valid url")
            }
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showError) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {}))
        }
    }
}


struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
let url: URL
var handleError: ((String) -> Void)?

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    return webView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    uiView.load(request)
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var parent: WebView
    
    init(_ parent: WebView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        //            self.parent.handleError?(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.parent.handleError?("Hello, fake error for testing")
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

on console I get this messages

> 2024-02-21 15:48:06.529734+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275]
> [Sandbox] Could not enable Mach bootstrap, errno = 1. 2024-02-21
> 15:48:06.529863+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275] [Sandbox]
> Could not enable Mach bootstrap, errno = 1. 2024-02-21
> 15:48:07.385311+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275] [Security]
> This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to
> UI unresponsiveness.
>
> 2024-02-21 15:48:07.385440+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275]
> [Security] This method should not be called on the main thread as it
> may lead to UI unresponsiveness.
>
> 2024-02-21 15:48:08.063187+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275]
> [Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController:
> 0x103033a00> on
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x10301e800> (from
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier*_:
> 0x10301e800>) which is already presenting
> <*TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView*:
> 0x103031e00>.
>
> 2024-02-21 15:48:08.225535+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275]
> [Security] This method should not be called on the main thread as it
> may lead to UI unresponsiveness.
>
> 2024-02-21 15:48:08.225651+0100 testRedirectWebView[32686:38145275]
> [Security] This method should not be called on the main thread as it
> may lead to UI unresponsiveness.

- I suport iOS 15
- project is in SwiftUI

Comment: Apparently Stack Overflow thinks I'm a bot now and does not make me answer. By the way, try using an overlay instead for showing the WebView and expand to cover the entire screen using a GeometryReader. Alerts will show up then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attach the alert to the `WebView` instead of the `Button`, the alert displays as expected with no console errors.

```swift
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showWebView) {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
        WebView(url: url) { error in
            self.errorMessage = error
            self.showError = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showError) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {}))
        }
    } else {
        Text("not valid url")
    }
}
```

I believe the error you saw came from the button trying to present the web page *and* the alert. This way, the button presents the web page, then the web page presents the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can you can show alerts when using a `fullScreenCover`. You should use an `overlay` maybe and expand it to cover the whole screen using a `GeometryReader`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showWebView = false
    @State private var showError = false
    @State private var errorMessage = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            VStack {
                Button("open WebView") {
                    if !showError {
                        showWebView = true
                    }
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                    if showWebView {
                        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
                            WebView(url: url) { error in
                                self.errorMessage = error
                                self.showError = true
                            }
                            .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                            
                        } else {
                            Text("not valid url")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showError) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(errorMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {}))
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

This way your alerts can be presented. Also, I've had no signs so far of the error you mentioned.